# CSS Flexbox incorrect on Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, flexbox

I have recently been developing a website using flexbox, and have been doing so on Chrome. The site looks perfect on Chrome (and Safari, according to users) however it has some serious issues when viewed on Firefox and IE. I have tried to look online for documentation on which prefixes to include in my CSS and how to make it appear normal on those browsers, but I truly cannot find a summation or tutorial anywhere. Here is a sample of my CSS code, containing flexboxs that do not display correctly on Firefox and IE -

```
.header {
  padding: 12px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin: 0px;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.header-box {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin: 0;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 70px;
  width: 1170px;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

This code is for a header bar along the top of the site. I thought by including the `display: -moz-box;` and such, that would allow it to be seen on Firefox, but the formatting is messed up in the sense that the box is not centered but instead along the left side of the screen, and the boxes within the header are all along the top of the parent container rather than on the bottom. Thank you for any insight you may have on this problem!

Comment: Firefox supports `display: flex` since version 20, you don't need `display: -moz-box`. And please post your html. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I think I found one of the culprits - it lies with the line `-webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;`. Adding another line of just `flex-flow: row wrap;` fixes some of the formatting issue for firefox at least, which makes me think that I probably have a lot of formatting commands prefixed by -webkit- that firefox can't read

Comment: Yes, I was just writing that in an answer. `-webkit-` is a vendor prefix, don't expect all browser to recognize it. Always include the standard, unprefixed version.

Answer (score 2):

In only works on webkit browsers because you only use

```css
-webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
```

You should use the standard

```css
flex-flow: row wrap;
```

Otherwise, the initial value `row nowrap` will be used instead.